# How Can I Update Data In HBase

Tags: hbase

I had the user data stored in HBase and i had c# client which uses HBase REST API to stores the data in HBase table.
There is possibility of updating the user data by multiple threads. How can i update the rows in Table and how can i apply the locking system on the rows. 
NOTE:- I am using the HBase REST API.

Answer (score 0):

Can you point us to the rest api you are following? afaik i have not seen one which is not depricated.

Apart from that i beleive the rest api would have been build upon the hbase api. And every 'Put' operation in hbase holds a row lock. i.e. The writes are atomic so you dont really have to care.

Comment: You mean two users cannot retrieve the row at a time

Comment: If user1 update the value then what will happen when user2 update the value. Can you please explain with ex. I have little bit confusion...

Comment: I am very new to HBase and i have many doubts.Can you provide the your email id. It may help me.

Answer (score 0):

The online documentation does not yet describe the ?check=put and ?check=delete parameters.  The source code seems to say that you should include an extra cell description at the end of your payload that specifies the old contents that must match before the operation is performed.